# Mongoose Virtual Populate 4.5 One-to-Many

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the Mongoose 4.5 virtual populate API and am unable to get the virtual field to populate on the one side of a one-to-many.

```
const FilmSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  slug: String,
  director: String
});

const DirectorSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  slug: String
});

DirectorSchema.virtual('films', {
  ref: 'Film',
  localField: 'slug',
  foreignField: 'director'
});

const Film = mongoose.model('Film', FilmSchema, 'film');
const Director = mongoose.model('Director', DirectorSchema, 'director');

Director.find({}).populate('films').exec()
  .then(data => res.send(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The director data is output as expected but without any mention of `films` and without throwing/logging any errors.

In the query log, it looks like Mongoose is trying to do what I ask:

```
Mongoose: director.find({}) { fields: undefined }
Mongoose: film.find({ director: { '$in': [ 'spielberg', 'zemeckis', 'nolan' ] } }) { fields: undefined }
```

I've tried several variations, such as:

- setting a `ref` to Director with `type: String` on `FilmSchema.director`
- setting a `ref` to Director with type ObjectId on `FilmSchema.director`
- replacing `slug` with a custom `_id` String

...and various combinations of the above.

I'm using the [docs example](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) and Valeri's recent [article](http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-virtual-populate.html) as guides.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**Versions:** Node: 6.3.0  /  MongoDB: 3.2.5  /  Mongoose: 4.5.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered by [vkarpov15](https://github.com/vkarpov15) on GitHub issues:

> Try `res.send(data.toObject({ virtuals: true }));` or setting `schema.options.toJSON = { virtuals: true }`. Virtuals are not included by default when you transform a mongoose doc into a pojo

Answer (score 1):

If you have set `schema.options.toJSON = { virtuals: true }` and are still not seeing your populated child objects, try explicitly calling `.toJSON()` - I was simply `console.log`ging my objects and the data was not showing up! DOH!

ie:

```
const director = await Director.findOne({}).populate('films');
console.log(director);

>> { _id: 5a5f598923294f047ae2f66f, name: 'spielberg', __v: 0};
```

but:

```
const director = await Director.findOne({}).populate('films');
console.log(director.toJSON());

>> { _id: 5a5f598923294f047ae2f66f, name: 'spielberg', __v: 0,
     films: [{_id: 5a5f598923294f047ae2f6bf, title:"ET"},{_id: 5a5f598923294f047ae2f30v, title:"Jaws"}]
     };
```